# Get count of active and inactive guest users in Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

We are working on a Graph section in our project to show monthly report of Active and Inactive Guest members. 
We found this API:

```
GET /reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts(period='{period_value}')
```

But this API is only returning count of Normal Members not Guest users.
Which API do I need to call to get Guest users count?

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the external users inside your tenant, all you should do is user the following API call: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?UserType eq 'Guest'

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT for your comment . But we need fields like "lastActivityDate", "teamChatMessageCount", "privateChatMessageCount","callCount". Which is available in getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail API but not  in graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?UserType eq 'Guest' .  Any other api for getting  those fields  ?

Comment: Please take a look at [Get Channel Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Let me know if this doesn't help you.